(Expo) Stripe iOS Build Error: "You did not provide an API key" despite Providing Key
I'm encountering an issue with Stripe integration in my Expo app when running it on a real iOS device.
Everything works fine on Android builds, iOS simulators, and Android simulators, but when I try to add a payment card on the real iOS build, I get the following error:
Error code: Failed You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.
What I’ve Done:
I followed the Expo/Stripe documentation and have provided the publishable key in the frontend using the  component, like this:
<StripeProvider
    publishableKey={process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PKEY}
    urlScheme="your-url-scheme" 
    merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.{{YOUR_APP_NAME}}" 
>

and on the backend i also tried:
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_5…6o', {apiVersion: '2024-04-10'});


The API keys are correctly set in the environment variables.
On Android, iOS simulators, and Android build, everything works as expected.
The issue happens only on real iOS devices.

Setup:

Expo SDK version: ~50.0.20
API version: 2024-04-10
@stripe/stripe-react-native: ~0.35.1
react-native: 0.73.6
Device: iPhone13 (iOS 18.1.1)

What I've Tried:

Verified that the API key is correct and correctly loaded in process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PKEY.
Double-checked the relevant documentation for iOS integration with Expo/Stripe, but nothing seems to address this specific error.

